# Back navigation in title bar - fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, back-button

There are many questions like this asked but everything I have tried seems to not work.
Essentially I have a main activity that calls different fragments depending on what the user clicks with the home fragment being default.
I would like to have a back button on the title bar, to go back to the previous fragment.

My fragment is called from the main activity like so:

```
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new nextFragment();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

But since ActionBarActivity activity is deprecated I need to extend AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity so I can use actionbar (I'm assuming this is what I need).
However then I am unable to switch to my fragment. So does anyone know how I could implement a back button in my fragment or how to use AppCompatActivity in this situation.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you add this `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your code?

Comment: I'm using a FragmentActivity.

Comment: Okay, so you can achieve the back button by extending AppCompatActivity and then implementing `appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thanks,
Where do I put "appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEn‌​abled(true);" and how do I switch from my main activity to its view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this if you extend `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Include these 2 lines ONLY if need to use Toolbar from layout xml as Action Bar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Add back navigation in the title bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //
        //Other works to be done in onCreate.....
        //
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            //Title bar back press triggers onBackPressed()
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Both navigation bar back press and title bar back press will trigger this method
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) { 
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
        } 
        else { 
            super.onBackPressed(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add Back Button in title bar, you must add the following code to your Fragment.

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
 AppCompatActivity AppCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
 AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    return view;
}
```

Don't forget to extend your MainActivity to AppCompatActivity.

You must then use this Java code in my Fragment class to react to the user tapping the back/up icon in the action bar.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:            
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've saved the last fragment used by calling

> addToBacktack(null).commit()

So the next step forward to call it is by overriding `onBackPressed()` in the activity hosting the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

So whenever you call the activity's `onBackPressed()` from the fragment, the fragment would go back to the last saved fragment.

Comment: Hi,
I don't actually see the back button on the title bar at all. And using the code you supplied came the error, "Can't resolve method 'onBackPressed'"

Comment: OnBackPressed is for the back button in the status bar (soft key) and not in the title bar.

Comment: Ok well my question was for back navigation in the title bar.

Comment: Pleas post your complete Fragment activity.

Comment: If you are looking for the arrow icon  (to represent back), you'll have to implement siu's solution, which is a combination of ahbi's and my solution.